# JSON to PHP variables

Tags: php, json, api

**This is the output of my JSON API call**

```
    {
  "response": {
    "status":200,
    "message":"",
    "startRow":0,
    "endRow":27,
    "totalRows":27,
    "data":[
      {
        "id":5,
        "start":42364236,
        "end":436234523,
        "startTimeSlot": 1,
        "endTimeSlot": 1,
        "subjects":["ne"],
        "teachers":["KRO"],
        "groups":["v1a"],
        "locations":["M92"],
        "type":"lesson",
        "remark":"Take care to bring your books",
        "valid":true,
        "cancelled":false,
        "modified":true,
        "moved":false,
        "new":false,
        "changeDescription":"The location has been changed from M13 to M92"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

*request through PHP*

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https:// [api request url]',
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

I want to story these results, maybe through an 'foreach' php command in variables. Like this:

```
foreach ($resp->response->data as $object): {

$subjects = $object->subjects
```

But how can I accomplish this? The way as described above doesn't work.. and I already tried many scripts..

Comment: You can just use json_decode() for converting json into associative arrays. When they are in those arrays, you can also do a foreach easily.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: use `json_decode($resp,true)` you will get php array ..

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually decoding the output of the download to an array.
You need to use json_decode(); on your data, to turn it either into an array or an object.

```
$resp = json_decode($resp);
```

will create an object.

```
$resp = json_decode($resp, true);
```

will create an array.

Comment: When i now dump $resp I get this response: Array ( [response] => Array ( [status] => 200 [message] => [details] => [eventId] => 0 [startRow] => 0 [endRow] => 1023 [totalRows] => 1023 [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 357185 [start] => 1429856400 [end] => 1429859400 [subjects] => Array ( [0] => lo ) ... Thanks so far! But how do I now store these arrays to the variables? When I try print_r($resp->response->data) or print_r($resp->$response->$data) I get an Undefined variable: response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you turning it into an object or an array? If you're using an array it would be $resp['response']['data'];

Comment: He thanks for your help. But still not there yet.. My code now looks like this: foreach ($vliegschema1['response']['data'] as $key => $info): lesgroep = $info['groups']; print_r($lesgroep);. And this nicely responses all of the 'goups' (like this: Array ( [0] => 1a1 ) Array ( [0] => 1ha2s ) Array ( [0] => 1ha2s ). But how do i store this in an variable and later echo this again? Cause I now get an Notice: Array to string conversion.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this code doesn't work is because curl get the json as a string. So what you're trying to do is looping through a normal string instead of an array.

You can use this to convert your json string to associative arrays:

```
json_decode($resp, true);
```

When it's converted in an associative array, you can simply use the data in the way it's been written in the json-format, and you can loop through it easily.